# Forming simple epistemic logic formula from a given sentence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, modal-logic

Sentence: I don't know if I know whether Lionel Messi is the GOAT.
$a$: I/Myself
$φ$: Lionel Messi is the GOAT

Attempt 1: $\,\lnot K_{a}\,(K_{a}φ \, \lor K_{a}\lnotφ)$ 
Attempt 2: $\,\lnot K_{a} \,\to \, (K_{a}φ \, \lor K_{a}\lnotφ)$ 
Attempt 3: $\,\lnot K_{a}φ \,\to \, K_{a} \lnot K_{a}φ$

Which attempt is more accurate?

Comment: Oh! You changed what you had… yes, now it is correct! … unless you are required to use that $b$ … in which case you could use a predicate $GOAT(x)$, i.e. use $GOAT(b)$

Comment: @Bram28 Cheers. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Bram28 I have updated the question. Please have a look at it again. Thanks.

Comment: I say still that first one. The second one isn’t even a proper sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Knowing whether Messi is the GOAT or not means that you either know that he is the GOAT, or know that he is not the GOAT.